visionOS RealityKit's physics simulation stops for certain entity.scale values
The setup:
My Vision Pro app loads uszd models created by a 3rd party app. These models have to be scaled to the right dimension for RealityKit.
I want to use physics for realistic movement of these entities, but this does not work as expected.
I thus wrote a demo test app based on Apple's immersive space app template (code below).
This app has two entities, a board and above a box that is a child of the board.
Both have a collision component and a physics body.
The board, and thus also its child the box, are scaled.
The problem:
If the scale factor is greater or equal 0.91, the box falls under gravity towards the board where it is stopped after some movements. This looks realistic.
However, if the scale factor is below 0.91, even 0.9, the movement of the box is immediately stopped on the board without any physics simulation.
Unfortunately, I am not able to upload screen recordings, but if the demo app is executed, one sees the effect immediately.
The question:
I cannot imagine that this behavior is correct. Can somebody confirm that this is a bug? If so I will write a bug report.
My demo app uses Xcode Version 16.0 (16A242d), simulator Version 16.0 (1038) and visionOS 2.0.
The code:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @Environment(AppModel.self) var appModel
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let boardEntity = makeBoard()
            content.add(boardEntity)
            
            let boxEntity = makeBox()
            boardEntity.addChild(boxEntity)

            moveBox(boxEntity, parentEntity: boardEntity)
        }
    }
    
    func makeBoard() -> ModelEntity {
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(width: 1.0, height: 0.05, depth: 1.0)
        var material = UnlitMaterial(); material.color.tint = .red
        let boardEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        
        let scale: Float = 0.91 // Physics does not run if scale < 0.91
        boardEntity.scale = [scale, scale, scale]
        
        boardEntity.transform.translation = [0, 0, -3]
        
        boardEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        
        boardEntity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, 
                                                       material: PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction: .infinity, restitution: 0.8), 
                                                       mode: .static)

        return boardEntity
    }
    
    func makeBox() -> ModelEntity {
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.2)
        var material = UnlitMaterial(); material.color.tint = .green
        let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        
        boxEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        
        boxEntity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, 
                                                     material: PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction: .infinity, restitution: 0.8), 
                                                     mode: .dynamic)

        return boxEntity
    }
    
    func moveBox(_ boxEntity:Entity, parentEntity: Entity)  {
        // Set position and orientation of the box
        let translation = SIMD3<Float>(0, 0.5, 0)
        // Turn the box by 45 degrees around the y axis
        let rotationY = simd_quatf(angle: Float(45.0 * .pi/180.0), axis: SIMD3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        let transform = Transform(rotation: rotationY, translation: translation)
        boxEntity.transform = transform
    }
    
}


By now, a Vision Pro engineer answered my post on Apple's developer forum, and found a workaround. Here is the tread:
Thanks for the detailed post. It makes it so much easier to help you. I think the physics simulation works, but the first few frames are being dropped. To prove this, I added a slight delay to enabling physics on the box and observed the expected physics behavior. Try this to see what I saw.
Task { @MainActor in
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3_000_000_000)
    
    boxEntity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default,
                                                 material: PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction: .infinity, restitution: 0.8),
                                                 mode: .dynamic)
}

Please file a bug using feedback assistant so our teams can investigate further. In the meantime you can work around this by adding the PhysicsBodyComponent in a Task (no additional delay needed).
Task { @MainActor in
    
    boxEntity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default,
                                                 material: PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction: .infinity, restitution: 0.8),
                                                 mode: .dynamic)
}


Not a full answer, but can confirm that I was able to reproduce your example on visionOS 2.0 (device and simulator) and that the simulation is not scale independent.
However, note that the behavior is not trivially wrong. Try changing the rotation to:
let rotationY = simd_quatf(angle: Float(45.0 * .pi/180.0), axis: normalize(SIMD3(x: 1, y: 1, z: 0)))

And you'll see plausible behavior down to very small scales.
To better see the effect in your example, start with both boxes as static and switch to dynamic on a button press. It's clear that the simulation is running, but the box settles quickly. If you don't like the behavior, consider changing the restitution.

Interesting! Unfortunately, changing the restitution is not a solution for my app. By now, a Vision Pro Engineer found a workaround that may work in some situations, and suggested to write a bug report, what I did. I will post this ASAP.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
